# How long can a guild name be in SWTOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

How long can a guild name be in SWTOR?

I am trying to determine a name for my group of friends, but we need to know how much room we have to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 24 character length limit on guild names in SWTOR.